# Accept meeting response on behalf of another user - ews-java-api EWS

Tags: java, exchange-server, ewsjavaapi

I have a super user that has Calendar read/write access to all users.

The super user creates an appointment in another user's Calendar:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);  

// create an event in userA's calendar
Folder calendarFolder = Folder.bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("userA@test.com")));

// Add userB as an attendee
appointment.getRequiredAttendees().add("userB@test.com"); 


appointment.save(calendarFolder.getId());
```

**Now I want to accept this appointment on behalf of `userA` and `userB`**